# UIKit UIViewController that passes a Binding to a SwiftUI View

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to make a SwiftUI `View` available in UIKit. Currently, there's a `Binding<Bool>` that I use for dismissing/presenting `DetailView`. Here's the working code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var presentingModal = false
    var body: some View {
        Button("Present") { self.presentingModal = true } /// tap button to present detail sheet
        .sheet(isPresented: $presentingModal) {
            DetailView(isPresentedBinding: $presentingModal) /// pass in the binding
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    var isPresented: Binding<Bool>? /// it's an optional so I do this instead of `@Binding var isPresented: Bool`
    var body: some View {
        Button("Done") { isPresented?.wrappedValue = false } /// tap the "Done" button to dismiss
    }
}
```

When you press the "Done" button, it sets `isPresented` to false, which dismisses the sheet. Now I want to present `DetailView` from a `UIViewController`. This is what I have so far:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func presentButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        let detailViewController = DetailView_UIKit()
        self.present(detailViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

/// wrap DetailView in a ViewController so it's easier to present
class DetailView_UIKit: UIViewController {
    
    init() {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func loadView() {
        
        view = UIView()

        /// Host the `DetailView`
        let detailViewController = UIHostingController(
            rootView: DetailView() /// I need to pass a Binding in here!
        )
        
        self.addChild(detailViewController)
        view.addSubview(detailViewController.view)
        detailViewController.view.frame = view.bounds
        detailViewController.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        detailViewController.didMove(toParent: self)
    }
    
    /// I want to call this function too
    func dismissThisViewController() {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

This works, but the "Done" button doesn't do anything... the `Binding` is still nil because I haven't assigned it to anything. How can I create some sort of `@State` property inside `DetailView_UIKit` so that I can pass it into `DetailView`? I would like `dismissThisViewController` to be called when that property is set to `false`. Or maybe creating an `@State` property isn't the right approach, I'm not sure.

#### SwiftUI flow:

```
ContentView (present)→ DetailView
        ◟________________◞
             Binding
```

#### UIKit flow:

```
ViewController (present)→ DetailView_UIKit → DetailView
                               ◟________________◞
                          Binding? Not sure what to put
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This does not work that way... you cannot close UIKit controller presented with `present..`  method by SwiftUI binding, you have to use corresponding UIKit `dismiss...` method.

Comment: @Asperi I know, I just want the Binding to call the dismiss method

Comment: I added some diagrams to clarify

Comment: Binding works between SwiftUI views, ContentView is SwiftUI view, DetailView_UIKit is not.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### So it turns out you can't use a `Binding` between a `UIViewController` and `View`.

In the end, I just made an optional closure in `DetailView`.

- If I present `DetailView_UIKit`, I will assign the closure to a dismiss function, but **not** pass in a `Binding` (you can't anyway).
- If I present `DetailView` directly, I will pass in the `Binding` as before, but **not** assign the closure.

Then, when I press the button inside `DetailView`, I will attempt to

1. Set the `Binding` to false
2. Call the closure

The order doesn't matter, because one of them will always be nil.

`DetailView`:

```
struct DetailView: View {
    var isPresented: Binding<Bool>? /// Optional `Binding` from before

    var donePressed: (() -> Void)? /// The optional closure I just added

    var body: some View {
        Button("Done") {

            /// Attempt to set the `Binding` (dismiss the `.sheet` if SwiftUI)
            isPresented?.wrappedValue = false

            /// Attempt to call the closure (call the `self.dismiss` if UIKit)
            donePressed?()

        }
    }
}
```

`DetailView_UIKit`:

```
override func loadView() {
    
    view = UIView()
    
    /// Host the `DetailView`
    let detailViewController = UIHostingController(
    rootView: DetailView() /// I DO NOT pass in a `Binding` here!
    )
    
    /// Assign the closure!
    detailViewController.donePressed = { [weak self] in
        self?.dismissThisViewController()
    }
    
    self.addChild(detailViewController)
    view.addSubview(detailViewController.view)
    detailViewController.view.frame = view.bounds
    detailViewController.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    detailViewController.didMove(toParent: self)
}

/// Call this function in the closure
func dismissThisViewController() {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```